# React JS Axios map

Tags: reactjs, api, dictionary, axios

I have 4 components in my project, that have the APIs, and there information.
the App.js includes the APIs:

This is in my **Country.js** Component

```js
render() {
  const DataGroup = this.props.countries.map((county) => {
    return <InfoData info={county} />;
  });

  const DataGroupAll = this.props.countriesAll.map((country) => {
    return <InfosData infos={country} />;
  });

  return (
    <div>
       {DataGroup}
       {DataGroupAll}
    </div>
  );
}
```

and the **InfoData.js**

```html
<div class="card-columns">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Date : {this.props.info.updated_at}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Confirmed : {this.props.info.today.confirmed}</p>
    <p class="card-text">Deaths : {this.props.info.today.deaths}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the **InfosData.js**

```js
<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card">
    <img src={this.props.infos.flag} width="180" height="130" />
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">Name : {this.props.infos.name}</h4>
      <p class="card-text">Capital : {this.props.infos.capital}</p>

      <p class="card-text">
        Currency :
        {this.props.infos.currencies.map((country) => {
          return country.code;
        })}
      </p>

      <p class="card-text">
        Languages :
        {this.props.infos.languages.map((country) => {
          return country.name + ',';
        })}
      </p>
      <p class="card-text">Timezones : {this.props.infos.timezones}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but all the information I got will be in separate cards, how can I combine them by the country code ?

Comment: Maybe InfoData should be a child component of InfosData.